# How to allow all kinds of letters from all alphabets in preg_replace with php?

Tags: php, regex

The issue: [image]

Basically when it sees type of letter that regex don't allow it messes up with the link.

My function in php to convert the names that are read from database into links:

```
function convertActor($str) {
$regex = "/([a-zA-Z-.' ])+/";
$str = preg_replace($regex, "<a href='/pretraga.php?q=$0' title='$0' class='actor'>$0</a>", $str);
return $str;

}
```

Also I want to allow spaces, dashes, dots and single quotes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will the name always have two words?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder  Three or more actually, the comma (,) would be a separator.

Comment: So... I've tried something out. Please check my answer to see if it fits your code. I'm grossly inexperienced in `PHP`, so I don't know if it'll even work for you :P

Answer (score 0):

The follwing regex should work for you

```
[^\u0000-\u007F ]|[a-zA-Z-.' ]\g
```

**[^\u0000-\u007F ] :** will match all non English Unicode characters.

**[a-zA-Z-.' ]:** will match English alphabets

**For PHP use this** : `[^\\u0000-\\u007F]|[a-zA-Z-.']`

Comment: One question: if the `\u0000` is given inside the character set `[]`, won't it try to match `\u` and 4 `0`s?

Comment: Right, it tried to match \u on regex101.com so it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sejoo it depends on the language. Not sure about php, but Python, for example, it will work correctly.

Comment: Well, I stated in the title for what language i need regex. The problem is still on :/

Comment: @Sejoo : added different regex for php in my answer, try that

Comment: @NitinDhomse No sir, it matches the whole string. 
 https://regex101.com/r/14a8Sd/4

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$regex = "/(?:[a-zA-Z.\-' ]|[^\\u0000-\\u007F,])+/";
```

Which converts `régime, Coffehouse Coder, Apple` into
`'<a href='/pretraga.php?q=régime' title='régime' class='actor'>régime</a>,<a href='/pretraga.php?q= Coffehouse Coder' title=' Coffehouse Coder' class='actor'> Coffehouse Coder</a>,<a href='/pretraga.php?q= Apple' title=' Apple' class='actor'> Apple</a>'`,

here on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/14a8Sd/3).

Comment: @NitinDhomse Thanks for your link, but OP wants the regex in PHP. I tried changing the language to PCRE (Server), and it doesn't work correcly there, but works seems to work fine at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/14a8Sd/1)

Comment: Could you help me out here?

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 20 ... I also get this.

Comment: Have you added the double back-slash in `\\u0000`?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder Yes.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder On my localhost apache, it gives error providen above. But on my server where i host webiste string becomes "N/A" whic i specified to be if string is empty.

Comment: What is the sample text you have given?

Comment: As it is on the picture.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that is looking for the solve, i found this temporary solution:

```
$regex = "/([\w-.' \á-\ÿ])+/";
```

Without dot and stuff but with spaces:

```
$regex = "/([a-zA-Z \á-\ÿ])+/";
```

**Cheers**